# Reading from .oni file results in out of order frames

Tags: c++, linux, openni, asus-xtion

My issue is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381100/openni2-reading-recording-oni-in-the-wrong-order).  There was no solution there.  In hopes to find a solution and detail my specific setup, below shows the function used to read frames from the .oni file.  If this function is run with Type == 2 (i.e. runs for # of RGBD images, where Criteria is the #), running this function in a for loop should allow a user to access each image.  However, the indices for the color image and depth image do not match and are out of order.  This continues until the waitForAnyStream times out for all the following calls to IMG_pipeline::listen(...).

```
void IMG_pipeline::listen(int Type, int Criteria){
    int exitNumber;
    clock_t start = clock();
    double elapsedtime;
    openni::VideoFrameRef frame;
    int CurrentIMGCount=0;

    switch (Type){
    case 0:
    {
        exitNumber = -1;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        exitNumber = Criteria;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        exitNumber = -1;
        break;
    }
    }


    for (int i = 0;i!=exitNumber;i++){
        readyStream = -1;
        rc = openni::OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(streams, 2, &readyStream, SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        if (rc != openni::STATUS_OK)
        {
            printf("Wait failed! (timeout is %d ms)\n%s\n", SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT, openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError());
            //break;
        }

        switch (readyStream)
        {
        case 0:
        {
            // Depth
            depth.readFrame(&frame);
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            // Color
            color.readFrame(&frame);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("Unexpected stream: %i\n", readyStream);
            continue;
        }
        }


        int Height = frame.getHeight();
        int Width = frame.getWidth();

        cvColor.release();
        cvX.release();
        cvY.release();
        cvZ.release();

        cvColor = cv::Mat(Height, Width, CV_8UC3);
        cvX = cv::Mat(Height, Width, CV_32F);
        cvY = cv::Mat(Height, Width, CV_32F);
        cvZ = cv::Mat(Height, Width, CV_32F);

        switch (frame.getVideoMode().getPixelFormat())
        {
        case openni::PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_1_MM:
        case openni::PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM:
        {
            openni::DepthPixel* pDepth = (openni::DepthPixel*)frame.getData();
            int k =0;
            for (int ri = 0; ri<Height; ri++)
            {
                for (int ci = 0; ci<Width; ci++)
                {
                    float pdepth_val = pDepth[k];
                    openni::CoordinateConverter::convertDepthToWorld(depth, (float)ri, (float)ci, pdepth_val, &cvX.at<float>(ri,ci), &cvY.at<float>(ri,ci), &cvZ.at<float>(ri,ci));
                    k++;
                }
            }
            TotalFrames[0]++;
            XYZCaptured = true;
            printf("Frame Index: %i \n", frame.getFrameIndex());
            printf("Depth Captured. \n");
            break;
        }
        case openni::PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB888:
        {
            cvColor.data = (uchar*)frame.getData();
            TotalFrames[1]++;
            ColorCaptured = true;
            printf("Frame Index: %i \n", frame.getFrameIndex());
            printf("Color Captured. \n");
            break;
        }
        default:
            printf("Unknown format \n");
        }

        printf("Frame extracted. \n");
        if (ColorCaptured && XYZCaptured){
            if (NewButNotRead == true){
                IMGsMissed++;


            }
            else
                NewButNotRead = true;

            ColorCaptured = false;
            XYZCaptured = false;
            RGBD_out.clear();
            RGBD_out.push_back(cvX);
            RGBD_out.push_back(cvY);
            RGBD_out.push_back(cvZ);
            RGBD_out.push_back(cvColor);
            CurrentIMGCount++;
            printf("Image overwritten. \n");

        }
        elapsedtime=(clock()-start)/((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        printf("Time since listen initiation: %f \n \n", elapsedtime);
        if (CurrentIMGCount ==Criteria && Type == 2)
            return;
        else if (elapsedtime>(double)Criteria && Type==0)
            return;

    }
    frame.release();

}
```

Here is a console output example:

```
Frame Index: 1 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.004846 

Frame Index: 2 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.011601 

Frame Index: 1 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.012640 

Depth frame count: 3 
Color frame count: 2 
Frame Index: 54 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000067 

Frame Index: 57 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.005878 

Depth frame count: 4 
Color frame count: 3 
Frame Index: 96 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000079 

Frame Index: 99 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.003628 

Depth frame count: 5 
Color frame count: 4 
Frame Index: 126 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000048 

Frame Index: 130 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.004782 

Depth frame count: 6 
Color frame count: 5 
Frame Index: 152 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000065 

Frame Index: 156 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.008294 

Depth frame count: 7 
Color frame count: 6 
Frame Index: 181 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000045 

Frame Index: 185 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.004095 

Depth frame count: 8 
Color frame count: 7 
Frame Index: 208 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000054 

Frame Index: 212 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.004242 

Depth frame count: 9 
Color frame count: 8 
Frame Index: 236 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000092 

Frame Index: 240 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.005918 

Depth frame count: 10 
Color frame count: 9 
Frame Index: 261 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000731 

Frame Index: 262 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000877 

Frame Index: 266 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.009347 

Depth frame count: 11 
Color frame count: 11 
Frame Index: 286 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000047 

Frame Index: 290 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.006080 

Depth frame count: 12 
Color frame count: 12 
Frame Index: 311 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000072 

Frame Index: 315 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.006453 

Depth frame count: 13 
Color frame count: 13 
Frame Index: 337 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000062 

Frame Index: 341 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.007485 

Depth frame count: 14 
Color frame count: 14 
Frame Index: 367 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000042 

Frame Index: 371 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.003758 

Depth frame count: 15 
Color frame count: 15 
Frame Index: 390 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000073 

Frame Index: 395 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.007917 

Depth frame count: 16 
Color frame count: 16 
Frame Index: 416 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000105 

Frame Index: 421 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.007554 

Depth frame count: 17 
Color frame count: 17 
Frame Index: 453 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000060 

Frame Index: 458 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.006150 

Depth frame count: 18 
Color frame count: 18 
Frame Index: 481 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000074 

Frame Index: 486 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.007169 

Depth frame count: 19 
Color frame count: 19 
Frame Index: 517 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000045 

Frame Index: 522 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.004196 

Depth frame count: 20 
Color frame count: 20 
Frame Index: 547 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000071 

Frame Index: 552 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.007375 

Depth frame count: 21 
Color frame count: 21 
Frame Index: 625 
Color Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.000179 

Frame Index: 631 
Depth Captured. 
Frame extracted. 
Image overwritten. 
Time since listen initiation: 0.007922 

Depth frame count: 22 
Color frame count: 22 
Wait failed! (timeout is 2000 ms)
    waitForStreams: timeout reached

Unexpected stream: -1
Wait failed! (timeout is 2000 ms)
    waitForStreams: timeout reached

Unexpected stream: -1
Wait failed! (timeout is 2000 ms)
    waitForStreams: timeout reached

Unexpected stream: -1
Wait failed! (timeout is 2000 ms)
    waitForStreams: timeout reached

Unexpected stream: -1
Wait failed! (timeout is 2000 ms)
    waitForStreams: timeout reached

Unexpected stream: -1
Wait failed! (timeout is 2000 ms)
    waitForStreams: timeout reached

Unexpected stream: -1
Wait failed! (timeout is 2000 ms)
    waitForStreams: timeout reached

Unexpected stream: -1
```

And here is the call to IMG_pipeline::listen(...):

```
IMG_pipeline pip_inst;
std::string FileName = "/home/derek/Test Data/RGBD/RGBD_S2_R1";
int Type = 2;
int Criteria = 1;
std::vector<cv::Mat> OUT;
int NumMissedIMGs;

int Start;
int Stop;

pip_inst.connect(FileName);

while (true)
{
  pip_inst.listen(Type, Criteria);
  if (pip_inst.IsNewIMG()){
    OUT = pip_inst.GetImage();
    cv::imshow("Current Frame", OUT.at(3));
    char c = cv::waitKey(0);
    if (c == 'f')
    {
      printf("Depth frame count: %i \n", pip_inst.GetDepthFrameCount());
      printf("Color frame count: %i \n", pip_inst.GetColorFrameCount());

    }
    else
    {
      Start = pip_inst.GetColorFrameCount();
      break;
    }
    cv::destroyWindow("Current Frame");

  }


}
```

The color images are also alternating R, G, B tints.  I am sure that is an issue with what order the data is in cv::Mat however.

Even more interesting, a call to IMG_pipeline::listen(...) that goes through many frames has a different index result then running IMG_pipeline::listen(...) multiple times, incrementing through the .oni file.

Comment: This is interesting: `for (int i = 0;i!=exitNumber;i++)`, what happens when `i = -1`? You have a 1/3 chance of having `exitNumber` not being `-1`.

Comment: -1 indicates that stopping criteria is not a matter of frames counts.  The two scenarios (`Type==0`: Stop on a timer, `Type==2`: Stop on a total count of combined images- a color frame and depth frame).  The end of that loop you can see those exiting conditions.

Comment: The loop will continue, from 0 while i != -1.  The only way to get to -1 from zero by adding 1 each iteration is to overflow; but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: The return statements will exit the loop if satisfied, which are (provided the input `Criteria` is appropriate).  The loop exits in operation.  That does make a good point that the frame is not released.  Changed `return` to `break` which doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the RGB information was not being copied correctly due to the variance of uchar from compiler to compiler.  So the case statement for RGB information was changed to this:

```
case openni::PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB888:
        {
            openni::RGB888Pixel* imgbuffer = (openni::RGB888Pixel*)frame.getData();
            //cvColor.data = (uchar*)imgbuffer;
            memcpy( cvColor.data, imgbuffer, 3*frame.getHeight()*frame.getWidth()*sizeof(uint8_t));
            cv::cvtColor(cvColor,cvColor,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
            TotalFrames[1]++;
            ColorCaptured = true;
            printf("Frame Index: %i \n", frame.getFrameIndex());
            printf("Color Captured. \n");
            break;
        }
```

Additonally, to ensure that I am able to capture every frame, I slowed down the file play speed.  Which is interesting that opening an .oni file plays at a speed rather than grabbing at frame indices (I can only assume this is the speed at which it was captured).  Anyway, this is done with

```
Source.getPlaybackControl()->setSpeed(Ratio);
```

Where Source is my device and Ratio is a user specified float.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the speed of playback from the `oni` files using the [`setSpeed`](http://www.openni.ru/wp-content/doxygen/html/classopenni_1_1_playback_control.html#a3ba6436562df82179e118296f3c897ee) command. Setting the speed to -1 will ensure that frames can be read manually in sequence from the oni stream i.e. each time you call `waitForAnyStream` you are guaranteed to get the next frame in the stream. See "Playback Speed" [here](http://com.occipital.openni.s3.amazonaws.com/OpenNI_Programmers_Guide.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have recently used this approach.  It is by far the simplest way to look at each image consecutively.